# Kubeadm init issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Kubeadm init issue.

Config data versions:

```
os -rhel7.5
env -onprem server
docker - 19
kube - 18
```

Console output:

```
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
```

What goes wrong and how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your question so that it can be properly understood. Well formatted questions with clear explanations will get answers sooner than improperly formatted questions.

Comment: Can you check if kubelet is running as the error indicates? You can do that by using `systemctl status kubelet` command.

Comment: no, kubelet not running

Comment: Please try to run `init` again and after that check kubelet errors: `sudo journalctl -xeu kubelet` and update the question with it. Did you disabled `SELinux`?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the information you provided there are couple of things that can be done here. 

**First** you can check if docker`s native cgroupdriver and kubelet are  consistent. 
You can view the config of the kubelet by running:

```
cat /var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
```

To check docker config you can simply use:

```
docker info | grep Cgroup
```

If you need to change it you can do it like this:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
EOF
```

To change kubelet cgroup driver you have to:

```
`vi /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`
```

and update  `KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=<systemd or cgroupfs>`

**Second** possible solution could be disabling  swap. 
You can do that with these commands:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo sed -i '/ swap / s/^/#/' /etc/fstab
```

Reboot a machine after that and then perform `kubeadm reset` and try to initialize the cluster with `kubeadm init`.